# Makefile always says generated-file target is up to date, but generates target as expected

Tags: shell, makefile, generated-code

I have a script that, when run, generates a file.  I want to create a Makefile to run the script to generate the file if the generated file does not exist or if the script changes.

Here's a simplified version.  Let's say I have an executable script `gen_test.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "This is a generated file" > genfile.foo
```

And a Makefile like this:

```
#
# Test Makefile
#

GEN_SCRIPT = $(CURDIR)/gen_test.sh
GEN_FILE = $(CURDIR)/genfile.foo

$(GEN_FILE): $(GEN_SCRIPT)
        $(shell $(GEN_SCRIPT))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) $(GEN_FILE)
```

When I run `make`, I see the following output:

```
make: '/workspace/sw/bhshelto/temp/makefile_test/genfile.foo' is up to date.
```

but `genfile.foo` does in fact get generated.

What's going on here?  Why do I see the "is up to date" message, and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `shell` in a recipe? Just write `$(GEN_SCRIPT)` instead of `$(shell $(GEN_SCRIPT))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run `make`, I see the following output:
>
> ```
> make: '/workspace/sw/bhshelto/temp/makefile_test/genfile.foo' is up to date.
> ```
>
> but `genfile.foo` does in fact get generated.

As user657267 has suggested: remove the `$(shell)` from the recipe body.

Assuming that the `gen_test.sh` doesn't produce any output (or output only on stderr), the explanation for the behavior is rather simple:

1. The `make` detects that the `$(GEN_FILE)` needs to be rebuild and goes to invoke the rule.
2. Before the command invocation, `make` performs the expansion of the variables inside the commands. Due to the (unnecessary) `$(shell)`, the `$(GEN_SCRIPT)` gets invoked already during this expansion.
3. The `$(GEN_SCRIPT)` does it work, but produces no output, thus `$(shell $(GEN_SCRIPT))` is expanded to an empty string.
4. Make sees that the command is *empty*, and thus there is no command to run.
5. The `make` then again checks the files (in case the variable expansion has side-effects) and sees that the target is up-to-date. Yet, since the expanded command is empty, the `make` prints its generic `is up to date` message.